# Do these two sigma algebras agree

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

The first sigma-algebra is quite canonical on the set $\Omega$ of continuous functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the context of Brownian motion. Let $X_t: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \omega \mapsto \omega(t)$ then the first sigma algebra is defined as $\sigma(\text{all }X_t \text{ are measurable for }t\in [0,\infty)).$

The second one is the canonical sigma-algebra occuring in the context of martingale convergence, namely $\sigma(\bigcup_{n} \{ \sigma(\text{all }X_t \text{ are measurable for }t\in [0,n])\}).$

I am tempted to say that the answer is obviously yes, but I made the experience that sigma-algebras can sometimes be mean, so I wanted to get your confirmation.

Comment: Yeah, the sigma algebras coincide.